# Touch detection on UILabel inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a `UIScrollView` and inside this I have `UILabels`. I need to detect touch events for the `UILabels`. At the moment, it is detecting the touch inside the second label only. It ignores the first.

I have the code -

**Creating the UIScrollView**

```
backGroundView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
backGroundView.frame= self.view.frame;
backGroundView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[backGroundView setScrollEnabled:YES];
backGroundView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
backGroundView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
backGroundView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:backGroundView];
```

**Creating the `UILabel`**

```
UILabel *OneDay = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, stockChart.bounds.origin.y + stockChart.bounds.size.height + 35, 40, 30)];
OneDay.text = @"1d";
OneDay.tag = 1;
OneDay.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
OneDay.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
OneDay.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
OneDay.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[OneDay addGestureRecognizer:detectTimeFrameChange];
[backGroundView addSubview:OneDay];

UILabel *FiveDay = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, stockChart.bounds.origin.y + stockChart.bounds.size.height + 35, 40, 30)];
FiveDay.text = @"5d";
FiveDay.tag = 2;
FiveDay.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
FiveDay.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
FiveDay.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
FiveDay.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[FiveDay addGestureRecognizer:detectTimeFrameChange];
[backGroundView addSubview:FiveDay];
```

**Creating the gesturerecognizer**

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *detectTimeFrameChange = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(timeFrameLabelTapped:)];
detectTimeFrameChange.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[backGroundView addGestureRecognizer:detectTimeFrameChange];
```

**Handling gesture**

```
-(void)timeFrameLabelTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    if (recognizer.view.tag == 1) {
        NSLog(@"One pressed");
    }
    else if (recognizer.view.tag == 2){
        NSLog(@"2 pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685956/uiscrollview-touchesbegan just try this

Comment: Add [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender view]]; before if (recognizer.view.tag == 1) {...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this :

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *labelTap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTapped)];
    labelTap.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [yourLabel addGestureRecognizer:labelTap];
```

handle the touch tap event inside labelTapped method:

```
-(void)labelTapped
{
  //your code to handle tap
}
```

Comment: is it also possible to pass the tag of the UILabel. I will also implement few other UILabels, so I will have to detect which label was tapped

Comment: @AshishAgarwal: Yes I have just checked that code it is possible .

Comment: I have updated the question with the suggested changes. It detects only the second gesture at the moment

Comment: because your first label overridden by second.

Comment: @AshishAgarwal:refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237693/ios-adding-tapgesture-to-multiple-views

Answer (score 0):

Where have you written the touchesBegan?

If you want to detect the touches in the label you'll have to create a subclass of label and write your touchesBegan there to detect the touch events

Comment: this should be in comment.

Comment: >Where have u written the touchesBegan?  No.  That's not the case.  Ashish is using UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Initially it was touchesBega. I switched to gestureRecognizers after reading the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Touch events are not detected on `UIScrollview` for getting your requirement add tap gestures to your label.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured)];
        [OneDay addGestureRecognizer:singleTap]; 

  -(void)singleTapGestureCaptured{

        NSLog(@"touch detected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find using tapgesturerecogniser like that...

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = 
  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                          action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.scrollview addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

//The event handling method
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if(recognizer.view.tag == 1){}
    //Do stuff here...
}
```

Comment: is it also possible to pass the tag of the UILabel. I will also implement few other UILabels, so I will have to detect which label was tapped

Comment: I added it to all the labels - `[labelone addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap]; [labeltwo addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];`

and it is detecting only the tap in the last label that I added it to. Ignoring the first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to use the same gesture recognizer for multiple views. A gesture recognizer can only be attached to a single view at once. You are only receiving events from the last view, because that is the view the recognizer is currently attached to. To fix the issue, simply create a gesture recognizer for each view you want to detect touches in.