# Recognizing Longpress gesture on two Uibuttons in ios

Tags: ios

I have two UIbuttons,and I want to implement Longpressgesture on both.

So I wrote the below code..

```
-(void)viewdidLoad
{
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonLongPressed:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
    [Button1 addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    [Button2 addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

}

- (void)buttonLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{    
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {        

    }   
}
```

now my doubt is how shall I check which button is longpresses?

Thanks
Ranjit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that a gesture recognizer should be attached to just **one** view.  You should create a new instance for each button.

To answer your question, you can add tag values to your buttons:

```
Button1.tag = 1000;
Button2.tag = 1001;
```

Then test them in the recognizer:

```
UIView *view = sender.view;
int tag = view.tag;

if (tag == 1000) {
...
}
```

You can enter any tag values, but I often start at a high value like 1000 to avoid clashes with any other tags that I assign in Interface Builder.

Another option is to use a different handling function for each recognizer.

Comment: hey thanks tarmes for your reply..hey you mean that I should create one more instance of LOngpress and add my another button to it right?

Comment: That's right.  See here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747238/can-you-attach-a-uigesturerecognizer-to-multiple-views

Comment: then I can right two different @selectors and my problem will be solved right?

Comment: That's another option, yes.  It depends on your needs.

Comment: hey tarmes,please check this link and give me some solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255395/how-to-set-a-password-for-application-in-ios