# How to set a password for application in iOS

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I am developing an application in iOS where I want to provide a password option..where user can enter a password and set it,and later when he opens the app,it should first ask for password to enter,

So can we implement this?

Any ideas ,suggestions are welcomed.....

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: This question is much to broad, there are loads of things involved - handling the views, stocking the password, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe save the password in the NSUserDefaults and request that password if one is set...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Not secure; a user could mount a non-jailbroken phone and read the password from `Library/Preferences/appname.plist`.

Comment: hey matzino..could ypu please ellaborate..and what if I store in a plist

Comment: I have no experience with jailbroken phones and what the user can see with such phones. What is with SFHFKeychainUtils how Alan Zeino mentioned? That seems to me that is designed for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Save the password to the keychain. Don't store it anywhere else, if you care about security. You could use SFHFKeychainUtils to do this easily.

Comment: @ranjit, you may be misunderstanding StackOverflow protocol. When someone gives you a good answer, you give them a point (the up arrow key). When the answer is correct or works for you, you mark it as such - the tick mark. You have not given any credit for these answers, and that is why people are marking you down. It's easy for you to fix.. Meantime, as I will use some of these ideas, I will upvote them.