# Can we add single gesture on multiple views and make it working?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working on a sample of Pan Gesture. I am keen to know that can I add single gesture on two views?

My code is as follows:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(invokePanGesture:)];
[panGesture setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];

[btnGreen addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[btnYellow addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

my handler method is as follows:

```
- (void)invokePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

The problem now is gesture recognizer is considering only last view in my case `btnYellow` as its view. If I create two separate GestureRecognizer object it works. So please clear me that:

1. Is it possible to have single gesture in multiple views or not?
2. If yes then how?
3. If now then why?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567684/470964.

Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7883902/470964:
Maybe it's also a solution for your problem.
I think the answer is that the GestureRecognizer has only one view property, that will be set.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs for [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

A gesture recognizer operates on touches hit-tested to a **specific view** and all of that view’s **subviews**. It thus must be associated with that view. To make that association you must call the UIView method addGestureRecognizer:. A gesture recognizer does not participate in the view’s responder chain.

*So, in summary the only way a GestureRecognizer can operate on more than one view is if the recognizer operates on a superview of the other views.*

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just write your invokePanGesture method to do the same thing to both views at the same time?

Comment: I can't because I want to know that on which view the gesture is invoked and move that view only. If I do the same you are saying than it won't work. It will keep the both view object with same frame according to you.

Comment: Then why use a single gesture recognizer?