# adding one gesture recognizer to a few UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have the following code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showNewsStory:)];
[self.storyImageView_ addGestureRecognizer:showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer];
[self.storyTitleLabel_ addGestureRecognizer:showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer];
[self.storyImageFailedLabel_ addGestureRecognizer:showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer];
[self.storyImageFailedTextView_ addGestureRecognizer:showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer];
[showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer release];
```

It seems that this only works for one `UIView`, which is the last one added In other words a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and it's view is a one to one relationship. Is this correct? How do I fix this? Do I have to create a separate `UITapGestureRecog` for each?

Comment: You need to create separate UITapGesture for each

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there can be only one `UITapRecogniser` for one `UIView`. You have to take different recognizers for different views although their action can be same.
Also see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747238/can-you-attach-a-uigesturerecognizer-to-multiple-views) link.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showNewsStory:)];

[self.storyImageView_ addGestureRecognizer:showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer];
[showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer release];

showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showNewsStory:)];
[self.storyTitleLabel_ addGestureRecognizer:showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer];
[showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer release];

showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showNewsStory:)];
[self.storyImageFailedLabel_ addGestureRecognizer:showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer];
[showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer release];

showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showNewsStory:)];
[self.storyImageFailedTextView_ addGestureRecognizer:showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer];
[showNewsStoryTapGestureRecognizer release];
```

Comment: you are NOT adding the SAME `UITapGestureRecognizer` to different views. You are always creating new ones for each UIView:

`initWithTarget` initialises a new instance of `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just have to add the gesture recognizer to the view that contains your `storyImageView`, `storyTitleLabel`, etc. as its subviews.

Answer (score -1):

You can add Same `UITapGestureRecognizer` to multiple View using this code.

Steps Are:

1. First we create three view with tag
2. Then we create `NSMutableArray` and add this view to array
3. After that add UITapGestureRecognizer to view
4. In UITapGestureRecognizer method we check the tag of view to differentiate which view tapped.

> Here is the code for the steps:

```
-(Void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //First create three View
    UIView  *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (5 , 171, 152, 152)];    
    view1.tag = 1;    //add tag to view
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview: view1];

    UIView  *  view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 163, 171,  152, 152)];   
    view2.tag = 2;   //add tag to view
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview: view2];

    UIView * view3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 5, 330,  152, 152)];    
    view2.tag = 3;    //add tag to view
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview: view2];

    //Now create mutable array to hold our view
    NSMutableArray * ary=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [ary addObject:view1];
    [ary addObject:view2];
    [ary addObject:view3];


    //now we add tap gesture to view
    for (UIView *view in ary) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer * answerDoubleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(answerDoubleTapped:)];
        answerDoubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        [answer4View addGestureRecognizer:answerDoubleTapGesture];
    }
   }

-(void)answerDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //Check which view is tapped
    switch (recognizer.view.tag) {
        case 1:
        {
            NSLog(@"First View Tapped");
            break;
        }case 2:
        {
            NSLog(@"Second View Tapped");
            break;
        }case 3:
        {
            NSLog(@"Third View Tapped");
            break;
        }case 4:
        {
            NSLog(@"Forth View Tapped");
            break;
        }default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are NOT adding the SAME `UITapGestureRecognizer` to different views. You are always creating new ones for each UIView:

`UITapGestureRecognizer * answerDoubleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(answerDoubleTapped:)];`

`initWithTarget` initialises a new instance of `UITapGestureRecognizer`.