# objective-c adding UIGestureRcognizer to UIImageView in tableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell` which holds `UIImageView`'s. Now I want to add a  `UILongGestureRecognizer` to the `UIImageView`'s. But this does not work. The `UILongGestureRecognizer` works on self.view...

How to implement the `UILongGestureRecognizer` that it works on the `UIImageView`'s in the `UITableViewCell`'s?

#### TableViewController.h

```c
@interface MagTableViewController : UITableViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableContent;

@end
```

#### TableViewController.m

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];
    self.longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2;
    self.longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    //[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.longPress];  // This works! 
}

// [...]

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imvLeft = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    [imvLeft setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.tableContent[@"url"]]];
    imvLeft.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // added soryngod's hint, but does not
    // solve the problem, as only the last row of 5 is enabled...
    [imvLeft addGestureRecognizer:self.longPress];  // does not work... 

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imvLeft];

    return cell;
}

-(void)longPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
// do stuff

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting `imvLeft.userInteractionEnabled = YES`, you also need to make a distinct gesture recognizer for each image view. By design, `UIGestureRecognizer` must be associated with a single view.  The symptoms you are seeing are a result of the recognizer being unattached from the previous cell as each new one calls `addGestureRecognizer:`.

See related question: [Can you attach a UIGestureRecognizer to multiple views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747238/can-you-attach-a-uigesturerecognizer-to-multiple-views)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `imvLeft.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`
by default it is `NO`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2;
        longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        imvLeft.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [imvLeft addGestureRecognizer:self.longPress];
        [longPress release];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imvLeft];

    return cell;
}
```

And if you want to identify the imageview that was pressed

```
-(void)longPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{

 UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;

//do stuff
}
```

Comment: Somehow this just works on the last imageView (row) in a section. I have 5 rows in a section, all based on the same code. When a new section appears, the last imageView (row) of the previous section does not work anymore, just the new one...