# How to add UIGestureRecognizer to multiple UISliders?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7

I have a problem that when I try to add my Gesture Recognizer to many sliders using:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *sliderTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTapped:)] autorelease];
[slider addGestureRecognizer:sliderTap];
[slider2 addGestureRecognizer:sliderTap];
...
```

Only the last one is applied in the app. I have up to 10 sliders on the screen at one time. Is there a way I can make one UIGestureRecognizer apply to them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assign single UIGestureRecognizer to multiple slider, You need to create separate for each.

```
UIGestureRecognizer *sliderTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTapped:)] autorelease];
UIGestureRecognizer *sliderTap2 = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTapped2:)] autorelease];

[slider addGestureRecognizer:sliderTap];
[slider2 addGestureRecognizer:sliderTap2];
```

For Reference check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567684/1597744)

Comment: Thank you, answered my question perfectly, although I have stuck with one "sliderTapped" method.