# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

stuck for hours and still can't find the problem. I cannot add UITapGesture to two differentViews

```
@IBOutlet var topView: UIView
@IBOutlet var bottomView: UIView
```

userInteractionEnabled in topView and bottomView are enabled in storyboard

here's my code in ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapTheView:")
    self.topView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.bottomView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

this is the method for UITapGestureRecognizer

```
func tapTheView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    println("Hi")

}
```

but when I clicked the topView nothing happened, when I clicked the bottomView my app crash and show Thread 1: EXC_BAC_ACESS in this line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

I'm using Xcode 6 beta 2.

when I tried it in XCode 5.1.1 using the same code above (but with objective-c) it works. thanks you very much and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Are the outlets connected  properly? Try "if let view = self.topView { view.addGestureRecognizer(tap); println("ok"); } else { println("no!");}" etc.

Comment: hi, thanks for your time to reply.

I've checked many times and yes topView and bottomView connected to the scene in storyboard.

I've tried your code but still got some problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works without crash in Xcode beta 2. One thing is you have to add separate gestures for each view [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747238/can-you-attach-a-uigesturerecognizer-to-multiple-views). i.e

```
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapTheView:")
self.topView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

var tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapTheView:")
self.bottomView.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)
```

Comment: hi thank you very much. I didn't know if I can't add 1 instance of UITapGestureRecognizer to two differents view. it works if I made two different instance of UITapGestureRecognizer for each views