# UITapGestureRecognizer with tap event

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to fire event with UITapGestureRecognizer on different uiview but it is not working.

```
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tappedMe"))
        AUIView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        AUIView.tag = 1

BUIView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        BUIView.tag = 2


   func tappedMe()
    {

        if AUIView.tag == 1
        {
            println("1")
        }
         else if BUIView.tag == 2
        {
            println("2")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the same gesture recognizer to multiple views. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5567684/2043580) explains why.

Either declare a new gesture recognizer, or create a copy of the existing one before adding it to the other view.

```
BUIView.addGestureRecognizer(tap.copy())
```