# recognize the different view tag via UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I use the code below to add touch TapGestureRecognizer on 3 views.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *anUITapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomeThing:)];

view1.tag=1;
[view1 addGestureRecognizer:anUITapGestureRecognizer];

view2.tag=2;
[view2 addGestureRecognizer:anUITapGestureRecognizer];

//...

view3.tag=3;
[view3 addGestureRecognizer:anUITapGestureRecognizer];
```

same as

[image]

but if I tap view1, view2, view3, the code below will output 1, 2, 3

```
- (void)doSomething:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{

    NSString *s= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)tap.view.tag];

    NSLog(@"%@",s);

}
```

s always returns 3

your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[you can't do like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747238/can-you-attach-a-uigesturerecognizer-to-multiple-views)* .You need to make different `UITapGestureRecognizer` instances for each `UIView's`.

Answer (score 0):

UITapGestureRecognizer is to be be used with a single view. You would have to use use different instance of `UITapGestureRecognizer` for each view

Something like this

```
for (UIView *mView in myViews) {  //Where myViews is the array that contains all views you want to have gesture recognizer on.

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapPress = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapPress:)];
        [mView addGestureRecognizer:tapPress];
}
```

And

```
- (void)handleTapPress:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
    UIView *selectedView =(UIView *)[gesture view];
    switch(selectedView.tag)  //there goes your conditional logic
....
```

}

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

An instance of `UIGestureRecognizer` will work only with one view. `UIGestureRecognizer` has a single view property -

```
view

The view the gesture recognizer is attached to. (read-only)

@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *view

Discussion You attach (or add) a gesture recognizer to a UIView object using the addGestureRecognizer: method.
```

So your need to create separate instance of `UIGestureRecognizer` (in your case `UITapGestureRecognizer`) for each `view` and than add them to corresponding `view`. Like

```
UIView *viewA;
UIView *viewB;
UIView *viewC;

...
// views created and customized
...
[viewA setTag:1];
[viewB setTag:2];
[viewC setTag:3];
...

// creating separate gestures and adding them to respective views
UITapGestureRecognizer *viewAGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTouched:)];
[viewA addGestureRecognizer: viewAGestureRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *viewBGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTouched:)];
[viewB addGestureRecognizer: viewBGestureRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *viewCGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTouched:)];
[viewC addGestureRecognizer: viewCGestureRecognizer];


- (void) viewTouched:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    NSString *s= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)tap.view.tag];
    NSLog(@"%@",s);
}
```

Now it will print the corresponding `view's` `tag` (`1` for `viewA`, `2` for `viewB` & `3` for `viewC`)

**Note** :

Also you were doing the reverse rather than adding the `gesture` instance on `view` you were adding `view` on `gesture` as

```
[viewAGestureRecognizer addGestureRecognizer: viewA];
```

And you need to do it as

```
[viewA addGestureRecognizer: viewAGestureRecognizer];
```

and as above in answer.

Answer (score 0):

The UITapGestureRecognizer can only be added to one view.
If you want your output to be 1, 2, 3 when you tap view1, view2, view3, you have to instantiate 3 UITapGestureRecognizer with the same selector like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *anUITapGestureRecognizer1 = [UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *anUITapGestureRecognizer2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *anUITapGestureRecognizer3 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];

UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
view1.tag=1;
[self.view addSubview:view1];
[view1 addGestureRecognizer:anUITapGestureRecognizer1];

UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,150, 100, 100)];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
view2.tag=2;
[self.view addSubview:view2];
[view2 addGestureRecognizer:anUITapGestureRecognizer2];

UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 100, 100)];
view3.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
view3.tag=3;
[self.view addSubview:view3];
[view3 addGestureRecognizer:anUITapGestureRecognizer3];
```

```
- (void)doSomething:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {

    NSString *s= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)tap.view.tag];

    NSLog(@"%@",s); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think the way to implement this is

```
[view1 addGestureRecognizer: anUITapGestureRecognizer];
[view2 addGestureRecognizer: anUITapGestureRecognizer];
[view3 addGestureRecognizer: anUITapGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: if not create different instances of uitapgesturerecognizer for every view you have