# Show Image Bigger on tap gesture in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used third party lib to show array of images in a slider . The images in an array comes from server, now i want to show the image in a bigger image view on a tap gesture. When anyone of the image user tap it should be shown in big imageview. I have tried some code but it is not working. My code is,

```
  int i=0;

    tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandImage:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [_ImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [_ImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    tap = [_imagesData objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"TTT %@",tap);

    [self.view addSubview:_fullImage];
```

The method is ,

```
-(void)expandImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser
{
    [self.view addSubview:_fullImage];

    UIButton *closeButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    [closeButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   // [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Closetab) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_fullImage addSubview:closeButton];

    UIImageView *photoView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [photoView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [_fullImage addSubview:photoView];
   // photoView.accessibilityIdentifier = @"nature2.png";

    [_fullImage addSubview:_fullImage];

}
```

Comment: see  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747238/can-you-attach-a-uigesturerecognizer-to-multiple-views

Comment: let me check. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: it is not tapping and showing me the tapped imaged in an imagview. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: I think no need of this in inside the `-(void)expandImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser` , hide this `[self.view addSubview:_fullImage];` and this `[_fullImage addSubview:_fullImage];` and try once

Comment: and you forget to set the frame of your close button and photoView

Comment: can you show the code related to this `_fullImage`

Comment: actually , i have tried this code from net. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155242/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-oneeb).

Comment: i have used uiview name fullImage and on that view used UIImage View name fulImageView. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: you tried in wrong way, its add close button on every time on tapped

Comment: Slider? What does that mean? A UISlider? Are you saying that you have a small image on-screen, and you want to add a larger image on top of the smaller when the user taps? Finally, what do you mean "I have tried some code but it is not working"? Not working how? What does it do and how do that not meet your expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I attached the [sample project](https://www.sendspace.com/file/8khny1) , customize yourself

**step1**

create the one full screen view for preview the image (use one UIView, one close btn, one imageview)

```
@interface ViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate, TAPageControlDelegate>
{
NSTimer *timer;
NSInteger index;
//
IBOutlet UIImageView *imgfull;
IBOutlet UIView *fullimagevie;
IBOutlet UIButton *btnClose;
}
```

**step2**

add the gesture for tap the image event and set the frame of your duplicate view as bottom of viewcontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

 [self setviewframe:self.view.frame.size.height + 10];
self.imagesData = @[@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg"];
for(int i=0; i<self.imagesData.count;i++){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * i, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame))];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:i]];

   UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandImage:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tap.view.tag = i;
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
```

**step3**

handle the image tap for preview the image

```
-(void)expandImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser
 {
imgfull.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesData objectAtIndex:recogniser.view.tag]];
[UIView transitionWithView:fullimagevie
                  duration:0.4
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                   [self setviewframe:0];
                }
                completion:NULL];

}
```

**step4**

dismiss the bigger image view on tap the close button

```
- (IBAction)btnClose:(UIButton *)sender {

[UIView transitionWithView:fullimagevie
                  duration:0.4
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    [self setviewframe:self.view.frame.size.height + 10];
                }
                completion:NULL];

}
```

**step5**

create the common method for set the frame for your bigger imageview

```
-(void)setviewframe:(CGFloat)coordinate{
CGRect modifyframe = fullimagevie.frame;
modifyframe.origin.y = coordinate;
fullimagevie.frame = modifyframe;
}
```

Comment: Bro, i have passed the images array coming from my service , but it isn't displaying it. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - but it isn't displaying it -- means ..(its does not shows in iamgescorll or full imageview)

Comment: @Oneeb - which once bro

Comment: @Oneeb - can you show the code related to this `i have passed the images array coming from my service`

Comment: yup , i have shared in discussion. Check there. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155249/discussion-between-oneeb-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @Oneeb - I am waiting for your reply

Comment: I have s view on which i have used image view and i'm passing array of images to that image view as followed ur code but the images are not shown there, what to do there? .@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Oneeb - can you come on the chat discussion

Comment: @Oneeb - this is the link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155249/discussion-between-oneeb-and-anbu-karthik

Comment: Bro, its only showing first image in fullImageview when we click on a slider image. @Anbu.Karthik