# Swift - Multiple UILabel click events to same function

Tags: swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I need to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to multiple `UILabel` and they all need to go to the same function for handling.

What I have is this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label_something: UILabel!
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.myFunction))
label_something.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Recieved here:

```
@objc func myFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) { // Something... }
```

Working like a charm. Problem is that its only working with one UILabel (If adding `addGestureRecognizer(tap)` to multiple `UIlabel` it only works on the last one added)

**So my question is:**

How to achieve what I want to do here? Five different UILabels with tapRecognizer going to the same function

Comment: How did you determine `myFunction(sender:)` called only for one label? If you tap on the other label, It didn't call. Did you check with log?

Comment: Yes, a simple print("hepp") in the function only showed when clicking the one that worked.

Comment: Could you see here some more code? ie how you assign the `label_something`?

Comment: Why are you using label instead of a buttons?

Comment: @Sourcey86 Where did you add gesture for all other labels?

Comment: I mean, you have to add gesture for other labels too. like `label_something1.addGestureRecognizer(tap) label_something2.addGestureRecognizer(tap) label_something3.addGestureRecognizer(tap).... etc`

Comment: @Mani Samle like above. Instead of only label_something.addGestureRecognizer(tap) I have 5 rows of this  with the different labels. Everything is done the same. Not showed in example to shorten down the text.

Comment: did you create new Gesture or assigning the same gesture to all labels?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizer` is to be used with a single view, you have to create a new instance of `UIGestureRecognizer`

```
func setGesture() -> UITapGestureRecognizer {

     var myRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

     myRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.myFunction))
     return myRecognizer
}

label_something1.addGestureRecognizer(setGesture())    
label_something2.addGestureRecognizer(setGesture())
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add new instance from UITapGestureRecognizer its will work fine, for example

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.myFunction))
label_1.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.myFunction))
label_2.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Comment: Are you sure, need to create new gesture for every label?

Comment: @Mani A gesture recognizer can only be attached to one view. The reason is because each recognizer can have it's own gesture state (one is being triggered and the others are untouched).

Comment: i think yes, because if you use the same instance, it will be added for the last label.

Comment: @Crazyrems ya got your point. after seeing this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747238/can-you-attach-a-uigesturerecognizer-to-multiple-views

Comment: @Mani yes. Each label needs to get a tap gesture recognizer, i.e one `UITapGestureRecognizer` can be only assigned to single component, that's why the *last* label recognize the `tap`, it would automatically removed from the previous labels. However, all gestures can have the same selector method.

Comment: @AhmadF Ya got it. see my comment above. I think, It should be answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Each UIView needs its own recognizer, i have a little helper function for this case. Feel free to copy/paste.

```
private func addTapRecognizer(toView view: UIView) {
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapButton(sender:)))
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }

    @objc private func didTapButton(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let view = sender.view else {
            return
        }

        switch view {
        case self.imageView: // any view you want to check
        default:
            print(sender.debugDescription)
        }
     }
```