# adding gesture recognizer to uiimage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I have image slider .. i followed this tutorial to do it: [Create a Horizontal Paging UIScrollView with UIPageControl Swift 4 XCode 9](https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/create-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-uipagecontrol-swift-4-xcode-9-a3dddc845e92) and it's working perfectly..

now i want to add gesture recognizer on these images .. i tried to do it like this:

```
func createSlides() -> [banner] {

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

    let slide1:banner = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("banner", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! banner
    slide1.img.image = UIImage(named: "bannerex")
    slide1.img.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    let slide2:banner = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("banner", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! banner
    slide2.img.image = UIImage(named: "bannerex")
    slide2.img.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    let slide3:banner = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("banner", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! banner
    slide3.img.image = UIImage(named: "bannerex")
    slide3.img.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    return [slide1, slide2, slide3]
}

@objc func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("tapped")
    print(pageControl.currentPage)
}
```

but it's not working, nothing will happen.

How to solve this issue?

```
import UIKit

class banner: UIView {


@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

 }
```

Comment: Quick hint: as per Swift code convention, class names (in this case `banner`) should start with an uppercase letter :)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth thanks for that :) .. but this is has nothing to do with my problem right?

Comment: Nope, sure doesn't. Try setting `slide1.img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` (and for the others also).

Comment: @LinusGeffarth i did .. and worked only for the last image view in the array .. how to apply it to all?

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `Banner`? I'm guessing, that'd be a better place to put it.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth i just did posted it

Comment: See my answer below. I figured, instead of giving a short-hand answer, I'd do a more elaborate one that helps you get up and running, plus, it suggests best-practices :)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I really appreciate this! many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. `isUserInteractionEnabled` is `false` by default
2. you have to assign each image view a separate gesture recognizer

---

### Solution

Instead of setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true` for each image view individually, I suggest placing that code in the `Banner` class itself. Since it seems your initializing it from the storyboard, using the `awakeFromNib` function should work just fine:

```
class Banner: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
 }
```

In your `createSlides()` function, add a separate tap gesture to each view:

```
let slide1:banner = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("banner", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! banner
slide1.img.image = UIImage(named: "bannerex")
slide1.img.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped)))
```

or even better for scaling & no-code-redundancies:

```
function tap() -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
    return UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
}

let slide1:banner = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("banner", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! banner
slide1.img.image = UIImage(named: "bannerex")
slide1.img.addGestureRecognizer(tap())
```

Answer (score 2):

The `UITapGestureRecognizer` must be used with a single view only so you need to create different `UITapGestureRecognizer` for each image if you want to detect tap on each `image`. Read more [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747238/can-you-attach-a-uigesturerecognizer-to-multiple-views).

And you need to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true` for every `imageView`.

Comment: Happy to help.. :)

Comment: Downvotes are welcomed but please mention a reason in comment. That way it will be helpful.

Comment: no i won't downvote :) .. but can i accept @LinusGeffarth's answer since its the clearest answer?

Answer (score 0):

[Image views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview) ignore user events by default. If you want an image view to handle user interactions as well, change the value of its `isUserInteractionEnabled` property to true.

Comment: I just set that to true for all of the images in the array .. and worked only for the last image view in the list .. why?